# Using ham radio to communicate with an underground crew

Tags: electromagnetism, electronics, electrical-engineering, antennas, radio

In "Stranger things 3" Dustin uses a ham radio named Cerebro (an image https://www.reddit.com/r/StrangerThings/comments/fhrdml/will_cerebro_make_an_appearance_in_st4/) stationed on a hill above the town to communicate with Hopper and Murray at least a kilometer under ground below the towns shopping mall as his walkie talkie would be unable to reach them.

Question: It makes sense to me that the Cerebro produces stronger signal which can somehow reach underground. But how does using Cerebro enable the team under the mall to communicate to the Cerebro? My guess is that the Cerebro is not only more powerful but also more sensitive. Also can it reach underground and how deep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way this would work in reality in either direction. Any appreciable depth of rock and dirt is opaque to conventional radio. Real radio transmissions through rock require a purpose-built ultra low frequency repeater and receiver that can transmit on a frequency for which rock is partially transparent.

In the future I would suggest trying to formulate a question about a generalizable aspect of reality, rather than asking how a fictional thing would have worked. Doing so will also make it easier to do your own research by exposing the real physics concepts that you want to learn about.